# Elasticsearch scroll API returns {"message":null} on followup call

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm using elasticsearch's scroll API to fetch all documents of a type. The initial call works as expected, but when I make the second call with the updated token, I get

`{"message":null}`

instead of the next set of results.

I'm using nodejs with request.js and HARs to call the elastic search cluster, hope it's easy to understand the next piece of information:

First call:

```
var har = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: esURL + 'index/type/_search?scroll=2m'
};
```

Result:

```
{ _scroll_id: 'cXVlcnlUaGVuRmV0Y2g7NTs2OTgxNTpXeUt4MFpqaFRraW9GWUZ1dEREUGRnOzUyMzY2OkZjLWVtOHdIUXhPVlVjX1JOTEdpZnc7NTIzNjc6RmMtZW04d0hReE9WVWNfUk5MR2lmdzs1MjM1NzppckFITVpLYlJvYUZqN3hzSW05SEtROzUyMzY4OkZjLWVtOHdIUXhPVlVjX1JOTEdpZnc7MDs=',
  took: 10,
  timed_out: false,
  _shards: { total: 5, successful: 5, failed: 0 },
  hits: 
   { total: 96,
     max_score: 1,
     hits: 
      [ [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object],
        [Object] ] } }
```

Next call:

```
var har = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: esURL + '_search/scroll?scroll=2m&scroll_id=cXVlcnlUaGVuRmV0Y2g7NTs2OTgxNTpXeUt4MFpqaFRraW9GWUZ1dEREUGRnOzUyMzY2OkZjLWVtOHdIUXhPVlVjX1JOTEdpZnc7NTIzNjc6RmMtZW04d0hReE9WVWNfUk5MR2lmdzs1MjM1NzppckFITVpLYlJvYUZqN3hzSW05SEtROzUyMzY4OkZjLWVtOHdIUXhPVlVjX1JOTEdpZnc7MDs='
};
```

Result:

```
{ message: null }
```

Wondering if anyone has experienced this issue.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is with your initial call, you have not specified `search_type` as [`scan`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html?q=scan) so by default `query_then_fetch` is executed.

Your first call should be

```
var har = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: esURL + 'index/type/_search?search_type=scan&scroll=2m' 
};
```

Also if you check your ES logs, you would notice an error.

Comment: I have tried setting the search type to scan, but now I don't get any results. I'm using AWS ElasticSearch Service right now, there doesn't seem to be a way to access those logs. When I find some time to setup a local instance, I'll try to check that out. Thanks.